# JSforce login to salesforce from Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, api, oauth2, jsforce

My goal is to listen for Steaming API events from Chrome Extension.
In order to do that, obviously i must log in first and get a token.
As embarrassing as it is, i am stuck at User Login phase.
I have been following the [docs](https://jsforce.github.io/start/#web-browser) which describe the login procedure:

```
jsforce.browser.init({
  clientId: '[your OAuth2 client ID]',
  redirectUri: '[your OAuth2 redirect URI]'
});

jsforce.browser.on('connect', function(conn) {
  conn.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM Account', function(err, res) {
    if (err) { return handleError(err); }
    handleResult(res);
  });
});
```

i can get the redirect_url using `chrome.identity.getRedirectURL` but what would be the next step in this case ? i would get the access_token to that url and then what ? what should i do with the token ?

Following the [docs](https://jsforce.github.io/start/#web-browser), i can see that `jsforce.browser.init` is followed immediately by:

```
jsforce.browser.on('connect', function(conn) { ... });
```

But how does that `'connect'` event happens ?
The docs dont mention anything special regarding the access_token and where it should be passed, its like magically passed to the jsforce instance.

Please point me in the right direction, i am clearly missing something here.

Comment: you need to use the token to perform the other aspects, in this case subscribing to the channel. that rest api call requires token, so you can try that.

Comment: Thank you @identigral, looking at the link you have provided, it seems that using jsforce outside of salesforce domain is not possible without a backed which acts as a proxy.

Comment: One of the reasons for the proxy had to do with cross-origin requests (CORS) not being allowed on oAuth endpoints. This restriction has been [removed](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_security_oauth_cors.htm) in Salesforce's Winter '21 release that just rolled out. (Note: as the release notes indicate, the admin of SF org still has to allow your app/client to issue a cross-origin request, it's not an automatic opt-in). Whether there are other issues beyond CORS that require a proxy is unknown/unclear to us. Give it a shot, it might work without a proxy.